# What is al-Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah?

Tags: source-identification, books

What is al-Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah? Is it a book on Islamic fiqh?

I couldn't  find any information about it on the internet. Can someone please provide me with some information (review) about the book including its author and time period (when it was written)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al-Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah الموسوعة الفقهية means the fiqh (jurisprudence) Encyclopedia and refers to an effort of the ministry of awqaf (referring to the ministry of religious matters) from Kuwait to build up an encyclopedia of jurisprudence according to the four sunni madhabs. This is a work of around 40 years (1965-2005) with the participation of many scholars and consists in its final version of 45 (Big) Volumes.

For details take a look at the [Arabic Wikipedia article](https://ar.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B9%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%82%D9%87%D9%8A%D8%A9&oldid=65032563) or [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Encyclopedia_of_Islamic_Jurisprudence&oldid=1186979375).